# In jquery, how to loop each div, and show each div for 10 seconds, then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id='a'> Apple </div>
<div id='b'> Berry </div>
<div id='c'> Cherry </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(#a).hide;
    $(#b).hide;
    $(#c).hide;

    var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr.length; i++) {
            setInterval(function(){ arr[j].show(); }, 10 * 1000);
            arr[j].hide();
        }                
    }
});
```

Steps:
Hide all divs.
Loop 10 times. 
Show each div for 10 seconds, then hide.

In this example, there are 3 divs. There could be more or less divs. So some kind of array is needed, I guess.

Comment: Please post the code you tried so far? Does the loop needs to infinite or it should run only once?

Answer (score 1):

Get all div's, use `setTimeOut` inside promise and resolve promise once the specified time is completed.

Inside `setTimeout`, mantain a index variable `i` which will loop over `div`, and set `i` index to `zero` once its value is less than the length of div (To start looping from first div).

```js
let prevDiv = null;

const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
const length = divs.length;

let i = 0;

const delay = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (prevDiv) {
        prevDiv.classList.remove('active');
        prevDiv.classList.add('hide');
      }
      i = i < divs.length ? i : 0;
      divs[i].classList.remove('hide');
      divs[i].classList.add('active');
      prevDiv = divs[i];
      i++;
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function calc() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    await delay();
  }
}

calc();
```

```css
.active {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='a' class="hide"> Apple </div>
<div id='b' class="hide"> Berry </div>
<div id='c' class="hide"> Cherry </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (I've shorted the time to 2 sec.)

```js
var arrIds = ["a", "b", "c"];

$(document).ready(function () {

  setInterval(function(){ 

   showAll();
   setTimeout(hideAll, 1*1000);

  }, 2*1000);
});

function showAll () {
  arrIds.forEach(function (e) {
   $('#'+e).removeClass('hidden');
  });
}

function hideAll () {
  arrIds.forEach(function (e) {
   $('#'+e).addClass('hidden');
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Started.
<div id="a" class="hidden"> Apple </div>
<div id="b" class="hidden"> Berry </div>
<div id="c" class="hidden"> Cherry </div>
```